# How to get return from join query if one of the tables is missing instead of error

Tags: ms-access, null

I have join query from 3 tables of which one is linked from other database and network location. Sometimes this location is unavailable and the linked table is missing. This causes query error of missing table.

Is it possible to make query work with and without linked table? When the data is missing column data should be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function such as the following to test the validity of the linked table prior to opening your form:

```vb
' ValidLinkedTableP  -  Lee Mac
' Predicate function returning True if a linked table exists and may be refreshed
Function ValidLinkedTableP(strTbl As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo error_handler
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs(strTbl)
    If tdf.Connect <> vbNullString Then
        tdf.RefreshLink
        ValidLinkedTableP = True
    End If

exit_function:
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Exit Function

error_handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3024 ' Link broken
        Case 3265 ' Table doesn't exist
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End Select
    Resume exit_function
End Function
```

The above will return `True` if the linked table exists within the current database with an unbroken link to the source table.

You can therefore evaluate the above prior to opening your form, and set the Record Source property of the form to the appropriate query dependent on the value returned by the above function.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Prior to opening the query, run some code to check if the sources are live and cancel if not.

Or choose to run another query not using the missing source.

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer. This query is feeding the form. If i don't run it the form would be useless and i need all other data. I can live without the missing data from the linked one, but i need most of the data that is present in the local tables. So i need solution to present available data + the linked if present. If not then null value is ok.

Comment: Then, if validating fails, replace the recordsource (the query) of your form with one that doesn't use the dead table(s).